# Syntax error while using ADO.NET with ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc, ado.net

I've been following this tutorial:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/522226/ADO-NET-cplustheplusrightplusway

to learn more about ADO.NET inside ASP.NET MVC. But if I put the following code inside an action

```
var connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["StoreCon"].ConnectionString;
        var _connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
        _connection.Open();

        using (var command = _connection.CreateCommand())
        {
            command.CommandText = @"SELECT * FROM dbo.group";
            using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
            {
                Console.WriteLine(reader[1]);
            }
        }
```

and I try to run it, I get a syntax error, as the system says, somewhere around "keyword `group`".

I'm new to MVC, so sorry if it's something trivial. I also added a connection string:-

```
<add name="StoreCon"
 connectionString=
   "Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;
    AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Items.mdf;Integrated Security=True"
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

and added a database called Items.mdf with a table called dbo.group with some rows named 'Name' and sample data.

Comment: try like : ``[dbo].[group]`` as ``group`` is a reserved word in sql

Comment: well that error is fixed, thank you! but I got another one - "Invalid attempt to read when no data is present.", even though I do have a corresponding table and sample data inside.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you need to provide escape group with square brackets as it is a reserved keyword,

```
SELECT * FROM [dbo].[group]
```

and from your comments then you need to use DataReader.Read to retrieve the data like this for **"Invalid attempt to read when no data is present"** error.

```
using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
{
  while (reader.Read()) 
  {
   //your code here
  }
}
```

It would be better if you write a separate question for second error.

Answer (score 1):

`group` is a reserved word in SQL, so you need to escape it with square brakets:

```
SELECT * FROM [dbo].[group]
```

Generally it is a good practice to escape all literal names you use in your query, to avoid such issues.

Comment: It worked, thank you! But now I've got another error - "Invalid attempt to read when no data is present.", but I do have the table And the sample data inside it. EDIT: I'll put your answer as right as soon as I'm able to (time limit)

Comment: @NemanjaT I have added the answer for your second error but I will suggest if your post a separate question for this error.

Comment: @NemanjaT, you need to call `Read` method on the reader: `reader.Read(); Console.WriteLine(reader[1]);`

Comment: Thank you both very much! Worked out flawlessly